# No objects to concatenate when using dask with h5 files

Tags: python, memory-management, dask, h5py

I have a dozen of h5 files that are too big to fit in memory. The structure of those files is the following:

```
file1.h5
├image  [float64: 3341 × 126 × 256 × 256]
├pulse  [uint64: 126]
└train  [uint64: 3341]
```

The size of a single file is around 200 GB, so even in an HPC would be difficult to load more than three of those files in memory.

But even with a single file, I'm not able to use dask to load it. I'm getting the following error, most likely because a bad use of the API or because a wrong data structure. The latter I can fix it with some guidance:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dummy = dd.read_hdf('file1.h5', '/image')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-84ef3fa4152e> in <module>
      1 import dask.dataframe as dd
----> 2 dummy = dd.read_hdf('file1.h5', '/image')

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/hdf.py in read_hdf(pattern, key, start, stop, columns, chunksize, sorted_index, lock, mode)
    498                 mode=mode,
    499             )
--> 500             for path in paths
    501         ]
    502     )

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/hdf.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    498                 mode=mode,
    499             )
--> 500             for path in paths
    501         ]
    502     )

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/hdf.py in _read_single_hdf(path, key, start, stop, columns, chunksize, sorted_index, lock, mode)
    380         [
    381             one_path_one_key(path, k, start, s, columns, chunksize, d, lock)
--> 382             for k, s, d in zip(keys, stops, divisions)
    383         ]
    384     )

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py in concat(dfs, axis, join, interleave_partitions)
   1034         raise TypeError("dfs must be a list of DataFrames/Series objects")
   1035     if len(dfs) == 0:
-> 1036         raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
   1037     if len(dfs) == 1:
   1038         if axis == 1 and isinstance(dfs[0], Series):

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Any help will be appreciated :)